# MongoDB Current Op

Tags: mongodb

We have enabled authentication in our sharded cluster environment.
Admin user,read user & read write user are created in this environment.
I would like to grant access to Dev team to view currentOp output/command.
When tried using read/write user we are unable to run CurrentOp command.
We would like to keep away admin user from Dev team.
Please kindly help.

Comment: What version of MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are able to use MongoDB 2.6, you can create a custom role. You would need to apply the [inprog action](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#authr.inprog) to the cluster resource.

Take a look at [createRole](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/createRole/#dbcmd.createRole) and the [Create a Role](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/define-roles/) tutorial.

```
use admin
db.createRole(
  {
    role: "devRole",
    privileges:
    [
      { resource: { cluster: true }, actions: [ "inprog" ] }
    ],
    roles:
    [
      { role: "read", db: "test" }
    ]
  }
)
```